# I'm trying to store multiple elements into an Array/variable, then make an Assertion to verify those element text as expected using JavaScriptfunction

Tags: javascript, function, selenium

I need help: Using JavaScript function, I need to performed Store multiple element and get the Text  from each element and assert using loop. I'm unable to crate JS function as I'm beginner for JS function.

```
xpath = "//ui-table-1/div/following-sibling::div[@role='title']";
```

this Xpath will get 4 element which are: Economy, Business, Latitude, Premium

I need to create JavaScript function where I should get those 4elemnt text and verify in same function. Could anyone please help me on that. Thank you.

```js
function javaScriptStep() {
  let result = 'sample';
  callback(result);
}
```